# A sequence of nested radicals and its limit

Tags: nested-radicals

Please Help me in the following Problem

> What is the Number Of Natural Numbers ,$n\le30$ for which $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\cdots}}}$ is also a prime number.

The only way I am able to find to solve this is calculate each and every term once but it will be extremely lengthy. Please suggest me a shorter way

**NOTE** This is a NSEJS (STAGE-1) Problem

Comment: Suppose that $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\dots}}}$ actually converges to a real number $S$ (*This assumption should still be proven to have a complete argument*).  Then $S^2=\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\dots}}}\right)^2=n+S$, and rearranged that $S^2-S-n=0$.  Can you continue?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have reached the following  conclusion Let $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\cdots}}}=p$ where $p$ is a prime number $p^2=n+p$ so $p=\sqrt{n+p}$ Now putting $p$ a prime one by one since there are only 11 such prime numbers we will get all the values of n for which we get the results.Am I Right?

Comment: Rewriting again, we have $n=S(S-1)$.  How many values of $n\geq 30$ can be written as a product of a prime and a number one less than that prime?  (*How many prime numbers are there?  Is there a value of $n$ corresponding to each?*)

Comment: My final answer is that there are exactly 3 such prime numbers . This way it is extremely small as after the third integer all are coming larger than 30

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten to list an important condition or you have an inequality pointing in the wrong direction or with the wrong expression in the inequality.  Are you for some reason looking for $n\color{red}{\leq}30$ instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72149/discussion-between-s-bansal-and-jmoravitz).

Comment: This is not a well posed question.

Comment: Could you please explain why so that i could correct my fault @miracle173

Comment: do you want to know the number of natural numbers n<= 30 where this square root expression is a prime number?

Comment: Yes,the question states that.

Comment: I changed this to a question I hope this is ok.

Comment: Is this ok now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72154/discussion-between-miracle173-and-s-bansal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n = p^2 -p$, then $p^2 =n + p $, so $p = \sqrt{n + p}= \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n+p}}$, etc.

**Edit:**  My original answer, above, left a lot to the imagination.  The real work would be in analyzing the convergence of the sequence of nested radicals.  To this end, fix a positive number $n$, not necessarily an integer for now.  Define $a_k = a_k(n)$ by $a_1 = \sqrt{n}$, and $a_{k+1} = \sqrt{n + a_k}$ for $k \ge 1$.

**Claim:**

1. For fixed $k$, $a_k(n)$ is an increasing function of $n$.
2. For fixed $n$, $(a_k(n))_{k \ge 1}$ is an increasing sequence and
   bounded above, hence convergent to a limit $p = p(n)$.

The first claim can be proved by induction on $k$.  For the second claim, note that $a_2 - a_1 > 0$, and 
$$
(a_{k+1} - a_k)(a_{k+1} + a_k) = a_k - a_{k-1}
$$
for $k >1$.  By induction on $k$, $a_{k+1} - a_k > 0$ for all $k$. Now assume for the moment that $n \ge 1$.  Then $a_k \ge a_1 = \sqrt{n} \ge 1$.  Hence 
$$
(a_{k+1} - a_k) \le (1/2)( a_k - a_{k-1})
$$
for $k >1$.  It follow that the sequence  $(a_k(n))_{k \ge 1}$ is convergent.  But now if $0 < n < 1$,  $a_k(n) \le a_k(1) \le \lim_{k\to \infty} a_k(1)$, so again the sequence $(a_k(n))_{k \ge 1}$ is bounded above, and hence convergent.  Let $p = p(n)$ denote $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k(n)$.  Again, $p$ is not necessarily an integer let alone a prime.
This completes the proof of the claims.

Now fix $n>0$, and let $p = \lim_{k\to \infty} a_k(n)$. Then we have
$$
p = \sqrt{n + p},
$$
as follows from
$a_{k+1} = \sqrt{n + a_k}$.  Therefore $p^2 - p = n$, and thus $p$ is the unique positive root of the quadratic equation $p^2 - p = n$.  Conversely, if we start with a positive number $p > 1$ and put $n = p^2 - p$, then the sequence $a_k(n)$ converges to $p$.  Thus $p$ is the limit of the sequence of nested radicals $a_k(n)$ if and only if $p^2 - p = n$.

Now we can solve the original question by searching  for primes $p$ such that $p^2 - p \le 30$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the limit be $x$.  Then $\sqrt{n+x}=x$.  Thus $x^2-x-n=0$...  So $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4n}}2$.  $x$ is positive, so $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}2$.

So let's see:
$n=6 \implies x=3$

Say $x$ is a prime, $p$.  Then $p^2-p-n=0$, so $n=p(p-1)$...

It looks like infinitely many...
  (as there are infinitely many primes)

Comment: I may be wrong but I can only count three primes, $p = 2, 3, 5$.